# How to get Previous date from given date ex. If today is 5-Feb-2018 then i wants 5-Jan-2018

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For ex. in case of 5-Jan-2018  I wants to get 05-December-2017 like in case of February i need only month back remain year was same but in case of January I need month back and year back also

if date is 05-March-2018 
i need     05-february-2018

But 
If date is 05-January-2018
i need     05-December-2017

Comment: dateadd(month, -1, someDate)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select DATEADD(mm,-1,getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks @Anagha select DATEADD(mm,-1,getdate())

Comment: If that answers your question, then please accept it as an answer. You have a habit of leaving your questions - SO works best if people can searched for answered questions.